# Is there a way in {gtsummary} to divide one column by another in a tbl_regression table?

Tags: gtsummary

I have a tbl_regression table of a coxph object, with one x variable.
I want to create a new column "percent" by dividing stat_nevent by stat_n.

I tried modify_table_body() but the percent column did not show.

```
    cox.model<-coxph(formula = Surv(time, y) ~ x, data=df)

    cox.tbl<-tbl_regression(cox.model, exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
      add_n(location = "level") %>%
      add_nevent(location = "level") %>% 
      modify_table_body(
        ~ .x %>%
          dplyr::mutate(percent = stat_nevent/stat_n)
      )
```

Greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: It worked!

It only shows up after assigning a header label

%>%
  modify_header(percent = "**N(%)**")